# Create action not being called in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just started a new app where I want to take a postcode in a form and save it to the database. My problem is that the create action doesn't seem to be being called no matter what I try.

Routes:

```
root 'postcodes#new'
resources :postcodes, only: [:new ,:create]
```

Controller: postcodes_controller.rb

```
class PostcodesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @postcode = Postcode.new
  end

  def create
    @postcode = Postcode.new(postcode_params)
    if @postcode.save
      flash[:success] = 'Success'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Error'
    end
  end

  private

  def postcode_params
    params.require(:postcode).permit(:code)
  end
end
```

Model: postcode.rb

```
class Postcode < ApplicationRecord
  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

View: postcodes/new.haml

```
.container
  %form
    %fieldset.form-group
      = form_for @postcode do |f|
          = f.label :postcode
          = f.text_field :code, placeholder: 'Example Postcode', class: 'form-control'
        = f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

I've attempted to pass more options in the `form_for` such as the method and action and now I have a feeling it's a routing error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: *the create action doesn't seem to be being called* How do you tell? Did you check in your database that no record get created? Do you get an error message? Does your `create` method have a view, because you did not define a redirect at the end of the method.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. Nothing is added to the database when I submit the form and if I place a ``raise`` at the top of the create action nothing happens either.

Comment: What the server log tells you? Any error?

Comment: ``Processing by PostcodesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6nS4Cl8TonmtNUMp0PT/c2CM7aJQxj3OQn4sCpjQK0H+/FZ1rEkw/hZsexjA/GgJIkAN5Y0pC2Go23CvxdGKvw==", "postcode"=>{"code"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered postcodes/new.haml within layouts/application (7.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 83.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is a result of your HAML.

You do not need to use, nor should you use, a form HTML element outside the `form_for` method call.

The `form_for` method will handle generating this HTML element/tag for you.

You have:

```
.container
  %form
    %fieldset.form-group
      = form_for @postcode do |f|
          = f.label :postcode
          = f.text_field :code, placeholder: 'Example Postcode', class: 'form-control'
        = f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn ban-primary'
```

Which outputs an empty `<form>` element.

You should have:

```
.container        
  = form_for @postcode do |f|
   %fieldset.form-group  
     = f.label :postcode
     = f.text_field :code, placeholder: 'Example Postcode', class: 'form-control'
    = f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn ban-primary'
```

That should generate a proper `<form>` tag with the required `action` and `method` attributes populated with the right URL and 'post' so that your `create` action is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Funny thing is I knew I didn't need that but didn't realise it could cause an issue like that.

Comment: Same here ... was a bit surprised to see that as the culprit.